# `useLazyQuery` From Apollo Seems To Trigger Infinite Render Loop

Tags: reactjs, next.js, apollo

I try to write a Shopify component using Next.js and the Apollo Client.  This is my cart component, which always enters an infinite loop (hundreds of renders per second):

```
import { gql, useLazyQuery } from "@apollo/client"

export default function Cart() {
    const checkoutCreateMutation = gql`
        mutation checkoutCreate($input: CheckoutCreateInput!) {
            checkoutCreate(input: $input) {
                checkout {
                    id
                }
            }
        }
    `

    const cartLineItemsQuery = gql`
        query ($id: ID!) {
            node(id: $id) {
                id
            }
        }
    `
    const cartId = "MY_CART_ID"
    const [getCartItems, data] = useLazyQuery(cartLineItemsQuery)
    getCartItems({ variables: { id: cartId } })
    return (
        <p>This is your data: {JSON.stringify(data)}</p>
    )
}
```

I suspect that my queries may be wrongly formatted, but I'd still like to have an error thrown in this case instead of the infinite loop.  Or could the problem also be located outside of that component?  When I delete the `getCartItems(...)` line, no infinite loop occurs.

The reason I use `useLazyQuery` instead of `useQuery` is that this code is already reduced, originally I first look if a cart ID exists in the cache and if this is not the case I request a new cart ID, otherwise I query the content of the cart.

Answer (score 1):

I misunderstood the idea behing `useLazyQuery`.  It functions more similar to `useMutation`, where the execution triggers a rerendering.  In my case, the working solution was to use `useQuery` with a `skip` parameter, so the query will only execute if, e.g., the cart ID variable is defined.